# Disable Windows DNS search domain / set to `.`

Tags: windows, dns, domain-name

I use a resolver that responds with records on bare TLDs aka dotless domains - will add some info on why below if you're curious, but it's not related to the issue.

On Linux, it's possible to do so by removing `domain_search` from dhcpcd conf or similar option in other resolvers.

How can this be done on Windows? I've tried adding a `.` to search domains in Adapter -> IPv4 Advanced settings:
[image: Advanced TCP/IP Settings]

but it doesn't seem to work:

```
PS> Resolve-DnsName -Name theshake

Resolve-DnsName : theshake : The data is invalid
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName -Name theshake
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (theshake:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERROR_INVALID_DATA,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
```

But with the `-DnsOnly` flag, it works fine:

```
PS> Resolve-DnsName -Name theshake -DnsOnly

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
theshake                                       A      20    Answer     135.148.148.182
```

If it's not possible to add a `.`, then can searching domains be disabled completely? So that even single label domains are treated at FQDNs (theshake -> theshake.)?

If anyone wants to reproduce / test, can use this resolver:

```
139.144.68.241
139.144.68.242
```

which is from [HNSDNS](https://hnsdns.com/) that resolves [Handshake](https://handshake.org) domains